# defining #define macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if there was a way in C language to define `#define` like this:

```
#define something #define
something a 42
something b 42
```

Comment: Did you bother trying to compile this yourself first?

Comment: It is reasonable to infer that yes, this code was tried and it doesn't work, but the question is whether there is some other way to achieve a similar result to what was hoped for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  If the expansion of a macro generates something that looks like a preprocessor directive, it is not processed as one, leaving a `#` in the source code that is seen by the compiler proper, which will then object that the `#` is an unexpected token (syntax error).

### ISO/IEC 9899:2011

> #### 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> ¶3 The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed
>   as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one, but all pragma unary operator
>   expressions within it are then processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.

The 'pragma unary operator' referred to is the `_Pragma()` operator which takes a string literal.

The wording in C99 is very similar, and the wording is C89 is similar but doesn't mention the `_Pragma` operator because it didn't exist in C89.

---

You can find drafts of the C2011 standard at the Open Standard web site:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/

along with working papers, 'mailings' for the committee meetings, etc.

(JTC1 is Joint Technical Committee 1; SC22 is Standardization Committee 22 for programming languages; WG14 is Working Group 14, responsible for the C standard.  [WG21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/) is responsible for the C++ standard.)

You can obtain your own, personalized copy of the PDF of the standard from [ANSI](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+9899-2012) for 30 USD.  I regard that as a necessary investment for any serious C programmer.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that?

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible in C. Defining a macro in another macro is not allowed.

From [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf):

> 6.10.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> 3 The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence
>   is not processed  as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles
>   one, but all pragma unary operator expressions within it are then
>   processed as specified in 6.10.9 below.

Comment: Note that the URL given is not actually even the most recent draft of the C11 standard.  You should probably reference the PDF available from [ANSI](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+9899-2012) for 30 USD.

Comment: Quoted part is ok for this answer, but $30 is a lot for me :D

Comment: Think of it as an investment for the next ten years — it works out at under a cent a day.  If you're not a full-time C programmer, then it is less crucial, but most computing text books cost that much.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any idea why the C11 Standard from the ANSI website is 30 USD while the version from the ISO website is more than 200 USD?  http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=57853

Comment: Different organizations charge different amounts.  ANSI makes up in volume what it lacks in per unit price?  For the C99 standard, there was also a book containing both the standard and the rationale, costing about $60.  It was more expensive than the PDF from ANSI, but cheaper than the standard (paper or PDF, IIRC) from ISO itself.

Answer (score 1):

No. The preprocessor only does one pass, so in the end, the code that goes to the compiler includes a #define, which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define something based on the definition of other ,C provides `#ifdef` to achieve it

like:-

```
#define something
#ifdef something
#define a 42
#else
#define b 42
#endif
```